# Can a previously neutral mix of chemicals become acidic or alkaline somehow?

Tags: acid-base

This question relates to
[Is there any law for pH conservation in chemical reactions?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37784/is-there-any-law-for-ph-conservation-in-chemical-reactions)

I had basically the same question, but I did not get the answer I was looking for from the above link.
For me this comes from a cooking background. If I add some acid to ph-neutral food, is this acidity preserved? Of course, when I add water, the ph goes up, but the overall acidiy (for the lack of a better term) stays the same. To get ph back to neutral I will have to add some alkaline substance, right? Or can I do anything else to change the ph back to neutral.
Equivalently: when I eat something acidic, does my body somehow neutralize it, without me needing to eat something alkaline?
Furthermore, when I breath I loose carbondioxide, which should make my body a little more alkaline each breath, such that I have a natural desire for some acidic foods, right?
I hope your getting what I'm after.
An example would be great, something along the lines:
When you add vinegar to flour-dough and cook it, something happens and after that, the total acidity is less than it was before some specific reaction happened.
Thanks

Comment: There is no pH conservation law.

Comment: Also, no law of "conservation of acidity" in any form.

Comment: Yes, I know, but a few examples where my supposed conservation law is broken would help me, as the only way I know to neutralise some acid is to add some alkaline substance

Comment: *"Furthermore, when I breath I loose carbondioxide, which should make my body a little more alkaline each breath, such that I have a natural desire for some acidic foods, right?"* Careful, you're almost veering into pseudoscience territory there. Carbon dioxide gas isn't acidic: only dissolved carbon dioxide is (as it dissociates to $\ce{H+ + HCO3-}$), and that is regulated *very* strictly by buffer systems in the blood system. You know what, maybe look up a buffer? That's a good example which breaks your hypothesis: you can add strong acid or strong base, and the pH barely changes.

Comment: There is typical natural example of fermentation of ethanol in wine to acetic acid. Or, the opposite, in distilled spirits traces of created acetic acid react with ethanol, forming ethylacetate. Another case is ammonia or hydrogen chloride synthesis from elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think the source of confusion is connecting the general notion of neutrality with pH=7.0. pH is just a scale for representing the concentration of hydrogen ions in water =-log [$\ce{H+}$]. Unfortunately, companies have misused the term to a large extent by marketing.

What do you think about ethanol? Is it neutral? I cannot even measure its pH. What is the pH of cooking oil or dough? Yet cooking is an acid from a chemist's perspective.

In a strict sense you cannot even define the pH of "food". Our food is horribly complex mixture of simple to very complex molecules. There is no pH-neutral food. Food juices are acidic, baking soda is slightly basic, when they all go to the stomach, they all meet hydrochloric acid, which helps in breaking down the food.